# sed multi-line replacement with line merging

Tags: macos, shell, sed, replace

This may be a bit complex, but here it goes:
Assuming I have an XML that looks as follows:

```
<a>
<b>000</b>
<c>111</c>
<b>222</b>
<d>333</d>
<c>444</c>
</a>
```

How can I, using sed on a mac, get a resulting an XML that looks as follows:

```
<a>
<b>111 000</b>
<b>222</b>
<d>333</d>
<c>444</c>
</a>
```

Basically:

- Matching 2 consecutive lines that are of the form <b>...</b> followed by </c>...</c>
- Taking the value between <c>...</c> and placing it (plus a space character) right after <b> on the line before it
- Removing the second line <c>...</c>

Thank you.

If sed is too much for this, please advise anything else as long as I can run it from a mac shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most beautiful solution but it seams to work :-)

```
$ tr '\n' @ < input | sed  's#<b>\([0-9]\+\)</b>@<c>\([0-9]\+\)</c>#<b>\2 \1</b#g' | tr @ '\n'
```

output:

```
<a>
<b>111 000</b
<b>222</b>
<d>333</d>
<c>444</c>
</a>
```

or a bit more general:

```
$ tr '\n' @ < f1 | sed  's#<b>\([^<]*\)</b>@<c>\([^<]*\)</c>#<b>\2 \1</b#' | tr @ '\n'
```

using `[^<]` to match anything between brackets

Comment: Thanks a lot Fredrik, but I forgot to mention that the 1's, 2's etc were just placeholder text. I didn't actually mean the content of the content is numerical.
Can we make it generic? to work on anything in between the tags? I assume I would simply change \([0-9]\+\) into \(.*\)? Thanks again :)

Comment: the `*` is gready mening that it'll consume anything. Classic approach here is to use `[^<]`. See update

Comment: your "tr" trick inspired me to redo some other rules I've had. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby would support multi-line patterns:

`ruby -e 'print gets(nil).sub(/<b>([^\n]*)<\/b>\n<c>([^\n]*)<\/c>/m,"<b>\\2 \\1</b>")' file.txt`